# Problem in executing a jar file in ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: jre

I have latest ubuntu 14.04 LTS + java 1.7.0_55 + IcedTea 2.4.7 installed

However when i try to execute a jar file i get the notification:

"This application requires a newer version of the Java runtime. Please download and install the latest Java runtime from java.com. Then restart the application."

What can be problem?
Please help.

Thanks in advance and regards.

Sivaraman

Answer (score 0):

The jar file that you're trying to run has probably been compiled with a more recent version of java. You may be able to run it with java 8.
Here are the instructions to install java 8 on ubuntu:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. How ever my OS is the latest Ubuntu 14.04LTS and jre latest 1.7.0_55. Also the jre works under "WINDOWS-7" OS with jre 1.7.0_51 Since it did not work in earlier Ubuntu 12.04LTS, i had upgraded to 14.04LTS. Then why problem in Ubuntu only? Regards, Sivaraman

Answer (score 0):

You have Java Jdk but Jre is missing 
You need to install latest jre

Then u will be able to run jar files

Goto oracle.com 
Download the latest JRE

Follow this wiki to set it up

http://m.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JRE-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. How ever my OS is the latest Ubuntu 14.04LTS and jre latest 1.7.0_55. Also the jre works under "WINDOWS-7" OS with jre 1.7.0_51 Since it did not work in earlier Ubuntu 12.04LTS, i had upgraded to 14.04LTS. Then why problem in Ubuntu only? Regards, Sivaraman